# CMake cannot link statically on Linux (perfectly works on Windows)

Tags: linux, cmake, static-libraries, sfml, static-linking

I do have the following `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(testovnik)

include_directories(include)

file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.cpp" "include/*.hpp")
file(GLOB TESTS "tests/*.cpp")

set(EXECUTABLE_NAME "testovnik")

add_executable(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${SOURCES})

if(WIN32)
    set(SFML_ROOT "C:/lib/SFML")
endif()

set_target_properties(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} PROPERTIES VS_DEBUGGER_WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin")

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
set(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES TRUE)
find_package(SFML 2 REQUIRED graphics window system)
if(SFML_FOUND)
  include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})
  target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${SFML_LIBRARIES} ${SFML_DEPENDENCIES})
endif()
```

When I do `cmake` on Windows, it works perfectly. Creates a `.sln`, then I can go build the whole project and it works. Now I want to do the same on Linux, necessarily linking it statically. But it doesn't work. I get the following error:

```
[frynio@manjaro bin]$ cmake ..
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindSFML.cmake:355 (message):
  Could NOT find SFML (missing: SFML_GRAPHICS_LIBRARY SFML_WINDOW_LIBRARY
  SFML_SYSTEM_LIBRARY)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:22 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/frynio/projects/cpp/testovnik_cpp/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

If I comment/delete the line `set(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES TRUE)` then it works. I can change it to `set(SFML_STATIC TRUE)`, then it also works, `make` works too. But if I make the project, I get the executable, but still if I uninstall sfml (`sudo pacman -R sfml`) then I get the following error when trying to launch it:

```
[frynio@manjaro bin]$ ./testovnik
./testovnik: error while loading shared libraries: libsfml-graphics.so.2.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Is there any way to build my project and give it to somebody else without them having to have `sfml` installed?

Comment: Are you sure that you have static SFML libraries installed on Linux machine?

Comment: I don't. But when I copy them from the `sfml` download site (the ones with `-s`) it does pass, but it throws so many errors saying: `relocation [...] cannot be used when making a shared object` and it says I should compile with `-fPIC` (which doesn't help at all)

Comment: So your problem is not linking with SFML statically, but obtaining SFML static libraries, isn't it?

Comment: I guess that's true. But still, cannot fix that

Comment: "but it throws so many errors saying: `relocation [...] cannot be used when making a shared object` and it says I should compile with `-fPIC` (which doesn't help at all)" - It says that you need to have **SFML** itself to be compiled with -fPIC for being able to link with it.

Comment: "necessarily linking it statically". Why necessarily? What's wrong with
linking the SMFL shared libraries provided by your Linux package manager?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you are using Archlinux (pacman ?), you can see that the [sfml package](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/sfml/files/) only contains shared libaries...

You should consider to build from source the SFML library to get the static libraries...

ps: you can also use `pacman -Ql sfml`
Q: query mode
l: list files

Comment: Yes, you're right. If I got the source, then how can I make it build static libraries as well?